# Comparing against child property in generic/dynamic linq predicate with reflection

Tags: linq, generics, reflection, predicate, predicatebuilder

I am having to generically build a comparative predicate for an Entity Framework Linq query.  I'm using reflection and am able to build a single level Lambda expression without any trouble.  However where I am starting to get stuck is I have an Entity that has a relationship

```
public class Parent {
    public virtual Child child { get; set; }
    .... Other Stuff...
}

public class Child {
    public int property { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent parent { get; set; }
    .... Other Stuff.....
}
```

How can I can I pass in "Child.property" into Reflection to be able to create a lambda expression comparing and come up with a lambda expression similar to item => item.Child.property == value?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this:

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Parent), "item");
Expression child = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "child");
Expression childProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(child, "property");
int value = 1;
Expression comparison = Expression.Equal(childProperty, Expression.Constant(value));

Expression<Func<Parent, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Parent, bool>>(comparison, parameter);


var sample = new[] { new Parent() { child = new Child() { property = 1 } } };
var result = sample.Where(lambda.Compile());
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are wanting a generic solution supporting nested properties:

```
public Expression buildLambda(Type startingType, string propertyPath, object value) {

  var parameter=Expression.Parameter(startingType,"item");
  var valueExpression = Expression.Constant(value);
  var propertyExpression=propertyPath.Split('.').Aggregate(parameter,(Expression parent,string path)=>Expression.Property(parent,path));
  return Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(propertyExpression,valueExpression),parameter);
}
```

Comment: This works. How would you handle it for a collection?

Comment: @Kenci as in using property indexing? `Wibble[5].Value`

Comment: What I meant was what if the OP's Child property was a collection, and you wanted to wrap a "contains" around that collection so that your lambda would be something like: Parent.Where(x => someList.Contains(x.property);

Comment: @Kenchi then you would need to replace the Expression.Equal call.  You would need to construct a method invocation of the Contains method

Comment: @Kenci the hard part is you would need to know if you were calling contains on the collection itself or utilizing the linq Contains method.